# Weird behaviour with Laravel's routing

Tags: laravel, controller, routes

I have two resources controller named 'livre-dor' (golden book in english) and menus, for a restaurant website. Both of them have the basic CRUD function with 'index', 'store', 'create', 'show', 'update', 'edit' and 'destroy'. Only, I decided to add an exception to the delete method because I find annoying the fact that I need to create a form just for a link.

So, for both the controllers, I did the following with the "destroy" action:

```
/**
 * Remove the specified resource from storage.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function destroy($id)
{
    $message = Goldenbook::find($id);
    $message->delete();
    session()->flash('message', 'Message supprimé');
    return redirect('livre-dor');
}
```

This is for the 'livre-dor', 'menus' litteraly has the same lines excepted for `Goldenbook::find($id)` that becomes `Menu::find($id)`.

In my routing, I did the following :

```
Route::resource('livre-dor', 'GoldenbookController',['except' => ['destroy']]);
Route::get('/destroy/{id}', 'GoldenbookController@destroy')->name('livre-dor.destroy');
Route::resource('menus', 'MenusController', ['except' => ['destroy']]);
Route::get('/destroy/{id}', 'MenusController@destroy')->name('menus.destroy');
```

And in both my views, I did the following :

**index.blade.php**

```
<tbody>
        @foreach($messages as $message)
            <tr>
                <td>
                    {{ $message->nom }}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{ $message->message }}
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a href="{{route('livre-dor.destroy', $message->id)}}">Supprimer</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
```

So, this way, instead of going to 'livre-dor.destroy' via delete, we go via GET which is waaaay simplier (don't worry this will be protected later). When I first did the whole thing, everything worked until I got back to work on it two days later.

However, now, when I get to the 'livre-dor' index, I get the following: `Route [livre-dor.destroy] not defined. (View: D:\PHPStormProject\nekoba\resources\views\livre-dor\index.blade.php)`, while 'menus' shows up smoothly. And when I run `php artisan route:list`, I can't find 'livre-dor.destroy' anywhere :

[image: Laravel Route List]

Also, when I did `php artisan route:cache`, it destroyed menus.destroy route and added mine. I can't find the logic behind all this.

Thank you in advance, ask if you need to see something else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Route::get('/destroy/{id}', 'GoldenbookController@destroy')->name('livre-dor.destroy');
Route::get('/destroy/{id}', 'MenusController@destroy')->name('menus.destroy');
```

You cant have the same URIs for 2 different route methods. Have them with different names, e.g.

```
Route::get('/livre-dor/destroy/{id}', 'GoldenbookController@destroy')->name('livre-dor.destroy');
Route::get('/menus/destroy/{id}', 'MenusController@destroy')->name('menus.destroy');
```

Comment: Thank you, I still don't understand the why's and the how's I guess, but it works now

Answer (score 1):

Try writing custom destroy route before resource route, hopefully it would work.